# Raspberry timelapse movie on the fly

Tags: image, raspberry-pi, movie

I have a Raspberry on which I want to create a timelapse movie.
All examples I see in the internet FIRST save a bunch of images and THEN converts them into a movie all at once.

I want to create a movie over a long period of time so I can't save thousands of images. What I need is a tool that adds an image to a movie right after the image is captured.

Is there a chance to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a flaw in your logic, I think - by adding each image to the movie, you would necessarily be adding a full-frame, rather than only a diff frame.  This will result in higher quality, sure - but it will also not save you anything in terms of space as compared to saving the entire image.  The space savings you see in adding things to movies is all about that diff, rather than storing a full frame.

Doing a partial diff with check-frames at increments might work, but I'm not sure what format you're targeting, nor what codexes would be needed in order to arbitrarily tack on either a diff frame or a full frame, depending on some external condition - encoding usually takes place as a series of operations rather than singly.

Comment: I know video formats group several pictures together to encode them properly. Would be nice if a tool could sum them up internally but I could also live with adding a few images instead of a single one in order to support the encoding process.
A 6 minute clip should fit onto the rasperry without problems but the 9000 single images that are necessary are a little overload.
All I need is a significant reduction of images that must be provided for the encoder.

Comment: I kinda feel like you're going to end up taking apart a tool and hand-carving something yourself, to do this.  Alternatively, you could encode, say, 20 frames with the first being a full frame and the rest being diff frames, then erasing the source images.  You'd later have to join the movies together....

Comment: Yes a short intermediate movie is an interesting approach. That's quite close to what I imagined with the single pictures.

There are so many tools, do you know one that is a good choice?

Comment: I'm afraid I do not have a tool recommendation.  I do wonder whether there's a stack overflow site for raspberry pi, though I do not think so, just questions tagged for it.  Or perhaps a Linux group would be the best place to look?

Comment: I went through some examples showing complicated commands with numerous undocumented parameters.  
They either don't work for some not understandable reason or create output that can't be opened. Or both - create some output and then hang... No idea what's going on.  
This seems to be a real hard task :-(

Answer (score 1):

An answer but it isn't finished!
I need your help making this perfect!
Running in python2

```
import os, cv2
from picamera import PiCamera
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

now = datetime.now()
x = now.strftime("%Y")+"-"+now.strftime("%m")+"-"+now.strftime("%d")+"-"+now.strftime("%H")+"-"+now.strftime("%M")  #string of dateandtimestart

def main():
  imagenum = 100 #how many images
  period = 1 #seconds between images
  os.chdir ("/home/pi/t_lapse")
  os.mkdir(x)
  os.chdir(x)
  filename = x + ".avi"

  camera = PiCamera()
  camera.resolution=(1920,1088)
  camera.vflip = True
  camera.hflip = True
  camera.color_effects = (128,128) #makes a black and white image for IR camera
  sleep(0.1)
  out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID'), 30, (1920,1088))
  for c in range(imagenum):
      with PiRGBArray(camera, size=(1920,1088)) as output:
          camera.capture(output, 'bgr')
          imagec = output.array
          out.write(imagec)
          output.truncate(0) #trying to get more than 300mb files..
          pass
      sleep(period-0.5)
  camera.close()
  out.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

I've got this configured with with a few buttons and an OLED to select time spacing and frame numbers displayed on a OLED (code not shown above for simplicity but it is also here: https://github.com/gchennell/RPi-PiLapse )

This doesn't make videos larger than 366Mb which is some sort of limit I've reached and I don't know why - if anyone has a good suggestion I would appreciate it

Comment: it has become apparent that I am using up all my RAM possibly which is why I get a limit of file size - next steps are to create shorted vids and join them afterwards or on PC instead of the pi.